# Verify Sudoku Square

Tags: c++, sudoku, verify

I need help figuring out what is wrong and how to fix it.  I'm trying to make a program that verifies if a sudoku board is valid or not. I've got the check for if a row and if a column is valid but the square validation is where I'm struggling.  Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

int *board[9];
int row, col;
void *is_row_ok(void *param);
void *is_col_ok(void *param);
void *is_square_ok(void *param);

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        board[i] = new int[9];
    }

    string line;
    ifstream myFile("Testfile3.txt");

    for (int row = 0; row < 9; ++row)
    {
        string line;
        getline(myFile, line);

        stringstream iss(line);
        cout << endl;

        for (int col = 0; col < 9; ++col)
        {
           string val;
           getline(iss, val, ',');
           if (!iss.good())
                break;

            stringstream convertor(val);
            convertor >> board[row][col];
            cout << board[row][col] << "  ";
        }
    }

    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_t thread3;

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, is_row_ok, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, is_col_ok, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, is_square_ok, NULL);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
 }

void *is_col_ok(void *param)
{
    int element_count = 0;
    char element_value;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
        {
            element_count = 0;
            element_value = board[i][j];
            if (element_value != ' ')
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 9; ++k)
                {
                    if (board[k][j] == element_value)
                        element_count++;
                }
            }
            if (element_count >= 2)
            {
                cout << "Column " << j << " is invalid." << endl;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Column " << j << " is valid." << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *is_square_ok (void *param)
{
    int square = 0;
    int element_count = 0;
    char element_value;
    for (int m = 0; m < 9; m+3)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < 9; n+3)
        {
            for (int i = m; i < m+3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = n; j < n+3; j++)
                {
                    element_count = 0;
                    element_value = board[i][j];
                    if (element_value != ' ')
                    {
                        for (int k = m; k < m+3; k++)
                        {
                            for (int l = n; l < n+3; l++)
                            {
                                if (board[k][l] == element_value)
                                    element_count++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        square++;
        if (element_count >= 2)
        {
            cout <<"Square " << square << " is invalid." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<"column " << square << " is valid." << endl;
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I have purposely left out the row checking function because that is working fine.  If someone could help me figure out how to fix my square checking function that would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. if someone could take a look at my column checking function and see how i can make it only print out the column verification once, that would also be incredibly helpful.  Currently it prints out the verification for each column i believe 9 times due to the outer loop.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are intending debugging this, remove all the threading stuff, and simply call your functions in a single thread.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int m = 0; m < 9; m+3)
```

Here, "m+3" does absolutely nothing. It should be m+=3.